# GhPython vs Python: TypeErrorException from GH but not from Shell

Tags: python, exception, grasshopper

I am using a library called `py_openshowvar` to communicate with a Kuka robot arm from grasshopper.

Everything works fine if I run the program from a command line python shell. However, when I run the same thing from GhPython, I get the following:

[image: <code>TypeErrorException</code>]

Not sure why I get the exceptions with GhPython but not when I run it outside the GH environment. The program still connects to the server and retrieves/sends the info I need, but I want to make sure and address this exception.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell you how to fix the error as you do not provide the code that triggers it, but in substance it comes from the fact that GHPython is IronPython (an implementation of Python based on .Net) whereas Python Shell is an implementation written in C.

The two implementations are similar but you sometimes hit a difference.

In your case the script is expecting a `string` or `tuple` but gets an `IronPython.Runtime.Bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, got bytes when expecting str looks like a unicode string vs byte string problem. You do no describe what are the versions of your CPython and GHPython, but you should know that Python 2 strings are byte strings while Python 3 ones are unicode strings.

If in Python 2 you can force a litteral string to be unicode by prepending it with `u`: `u"foo"` is a unicode string. You can also *decode* a byte string to its unicode version: `b'ae\xe9\xe8'.decode('Latin1')` is the unicode string `u'aeéè'`